# Javascript replace string regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following string

```
hello[code:1], world [code:2], hello world
```

I want to replace this string to

```
hello <a href="someurl/1">someothercode</a>, world <a href="someurl/2">someothercode</a>, hello world
```

I want this String conversion using javascript reg ex

I tried

```
/\[code:(\d+)\]/
```

reg ex but not sure how to tokenize them

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Does this fulfill your needs?

```
mystring.replace(/\[code:([0-9]+)\]/g, '<a href="someurl/$1">somelink</a>');
```

Answer (score 5):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z92XX/)

```
var s = 'hello[code:1], world [code:2], hello world';

var codes = {
    1: '<a href="someurl/1">someothercode</a>',
    2: '<a href="someurl/2">someothercode</a>'
};

s = s.replace(/\[code:(\d*)\]/g, function(a, b) {
    return codes[b]
})

document.write(s)
​
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not completely clear on what you want, but this outputs your desired result:

```
"hello[code:1], world [code:2], hello world"
    .replace(/\[(.*?):(.*?)\]/g, '<a href="someurl/$2">someother$1</a>')
```

Output:

> `'hello<a href="someurl/1">someothercode</a>, world <a href="someurl/2">someothercode</a>, hello world'`