# Regular expression to replace string in javascripts

Tags: javascript, xml, regex

hi i have one XML file i just want to replace some path in XML.
XML hold path of some images like it has many record like below

```
tile5url="images/Balcony Sunset Pano_o_480_5.jpg"
```

so i just want to replace path . i just want to replace `"images/"` with some other path like `"newfolder/images/"` or anythings else i have used javascript to read XML using `XMLHttpRequest` object and generate `responseText`  to read XML

Thanks

Comment: So what's the problem.  Go ahead!

Comment: `tile5url.replace(/(images\/)/, 'newfolder/$1');`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript replace string regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537872/javascript-replace-string-regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 /tile5url="(images\/[^"]+)"/
```

And replace with

```
 tile5url="newfolder/$1"
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/gB4oT5